# Is it ok to decrease the size of a dataset to speedup hyperparameters search?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

When training deep architectures, I want to be able to select hyperparameters in a feasible time. However, if my dataset is very big, this can be very time-consuming.

Is it OK to reduce the size of the dataset to check which hyperparameters perform better and then train the full dataset? Would this bias my hyperparameters selection since the training setups are not the same?

Answer (score 4):

**Depends**. In your case, most probably **yes**

The hyper-parameters do not depend too strongly on the amount of *data* (as long as you have "enough") but on the *complexity of the data* (resp. its distribution). Reducing a dataset *can* mean to "change" the distribution of the data caused by statistical fluctuations.

On big datasets, you should be able to reduce the amount withouth *real* loss of the distribution shape. Try it! Use a classifier on the full dataset and one on the reduced. Are the metrics (Roc auc etc) the same? (maybe do that several times to get a good mean)

If they are, it should really not change the selection of the hyper-parameters.

Anyway, if you feel unsure whether the reduced dataset still has the same distribution, you may use it to get *close* to your best hyper-parameters and use the full distribution to find the best one in the end.

Comment: This is an interesting sub-optimization problem: what is an optimal subset to train the initial hyperparameters on?

Comment: I'm getting good results with a subset of size=0.1 in a fraction of training time (slightly better hyperparameter selection in a fraction of the time)

Comment: This really cannot be generalized in any way as it depends *only* on the size and the complexity of the data-set. Sometimes even your full data-set is way to small, sometimes a tiny fraction represents everything. Simple trial and error.